# props attributes aren't updated

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

on a component I'm receiving **blog** object through **props**

```js
props: {
  blog: {
    type: Object,
    default: null,
  },
}
```

here I declare comments in data

```
  data: () => ({
    comments: [],
    // rest needed variables
  }),
```

and on the created method of that component I'm doing this:

```js
    
created() {
  if (this.blog && this.blog.comments) {
    this.comments = [];
    this.$nextTick().then(() => {
      this.comments = this.$srv.myMethod(this.blog.comments);
      console.log('this.comments);
      this.$root.$emit('comments', this.blog, this.comments);
    });
  } else {
    // rest of code
  }
},
```

the problem here is that **this.blog.comments** isn't updated.

I expect to get changes whenever a change occur. any insights please ?

Comment: you have not shown enough code for others to help you

Comment: since the code you'ev posted does not update `this.blog.comments` it seems only natural that `this.blog.comments isn't updated`

Comment: @Bravo and so what I'm supposed to do to make this code listen to updates ?

Comment: I wonder why this question has been closed! I even didn't get any indication to improve it, what details are missing ??

Comment: here's a clue ... your problem statement is *the problem here is that this.blog.comments isn't updated.* ... so where, **in the code you posted**, do you think `this.blog.comments` could possibly be updated?

Comment: @Bravo definitely on the component from where I'm receiving blog props! (don't take me for a genius, I'm on my first steps with vuejs so I don't exactly know how things are going)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are using `created` hook that is only executed 1 time when you create the component.

To check your prop changes you can use a watcher:

```js
  watch: {
    blog: {
      handler(newValue) {
        // Your stuff here newValue contains the blog object updated
      },
      deep: true
    }
  }
```

But if you only need `blog.comments` maybe is better to use your prop like `blogComments` as array and watch only this prop instead the full object.

Comment: according to the given code could you insights me how to complete the rest of the watch method ? I didn't find a way to it

Comment: Your current code is not clear. I do not understand why are you using $nextTick() to create a promise. But if you want to emit the updated value you do not need to use $nextTick(). You can emit your new data inside the watcher: `this.$root.$emit('updateComments', newValue.comments);`